# rtorrent fails downloads over 4GB on raspberry pi

Tags: download, raspberry-pi, raspbian, hashing, rtorrent

I'm running libtorrent/rtorrent master (13.7) on raspi 3b+ with raspbian.
I can download torrents under 4GB in size without any problems (for example debian netinstall at around 290MB). However downloading anything roughly bigger than 4GB will result in a hashfail every time. To clarify, the download of even big files finishes but when hashing the finished download it detects a hash fail. Sometimes as early as 200MB into the file (out of say a 4.6GB file).
The downloads are saved to an external 4TB hard drive connected via USB and formatted with exFAT. The drive itself is encrypted using veracrypt.

At first I suspected it had something to do with the preallocate feature of rtorrent. I tried disabling it but the results are the same. I'm also not sure why the hash corruption is not caught mid download as every chunk should be checked separately.
I don't think it's a hardware failure as the drive is new and has not shown problems otherwise.
I have tried installing rtorrent from `apt` before which shows the same symptoms. I installed the self compiled version afterwards which is what I'm currently using.

Running rtorrent from my desktop on the same torrents that fail on the raspberry works flawlessly.

Comment: If your external drive is formatted as FAT32 then that is the problem.

Comment: It's formatted in exFAT though.

Comment: Then please show us how your disk is arranged. [Edit] your question to show whether the veracrypt volume is full disk, how it is created and how you know it is exFAT. How do you know your system has exFAT support? It seems that it must be separately enabled... https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-exfat/

Comment: Can you successfully copy a 4GB+ sized file to this external drive?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I can. I downloaded a larger Linux distro on my desktop with rtorrent and then copied it onto the external. Then loaded it in rtorrent (on the raspi) so it can get hashed and it passed the hash check without problems. The problems only occur when the large files are acquired directly through rtorrent (on the raspi).